# cannot establish a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net

I have a web app that I developed using Visual Web Developer 2010. The database is local inside the solution:

```
<add name="SFDBConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SFDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm trying to run the app on another machine using Visual Studio 2010 instead of the web developer and it's giving me the following error when it tries to connect to the database:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Does anybody has any idea on what could be happening?

Comment: Show us the code you use to connect to the DB

Comment: is there a sql express on the machine with VS2010?

Comment: i'm connecting to the database using linqToSql

Comment: there is sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error message means exactly what it says... 
Can you connect to the SQL server through UI client (like, management studio)? If yes - how do you do that (user/password or Windows authentication; what is the server name)?
What is the connection string? You put here the connection string to SQL Express (which works; so it isn't quite helpful) - but forgot to put the connection string that *doesn't* work.
If you can connect in UI, and connection string is correct - there is no reason why the code would throw an error!

Comment: on sql server management i'm trying to enter my windows authentication, but the username and password are disabled.

Comment: 1. Are you successful logging in (with windows authentication)?
2. (as somebody asked) is there sql server *express* running? (you mention sql server 2005, which has different connection string).